# How can I show an error if user signs in via Facebook and desn't provide his email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

In my web app, I have a devise gem for registration and 2 omniauth gems (Google and Facebook). The situation is as follows: If a user doesn't provide an email signing up with Facebook, the application raises an exception: `Validation failed: Email can't be blank`. This is how my `from_omniauth` method looks like in a User model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth, sign_in_resource = nil)

    # Get the identity and usesr if they exist
    identity = Identity.find_from_oauth(auth)

    # If a signed_in_resosurce is provided it always overrides the existing user
    # to prvent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
    user = sign_in_resource ? sign_in_resource : identity.user

    # Create the user if needed
    if user.nil?

      # Get the exsiting user by email *Assuming that they provide valid_email address.
      user = User.where(email: auth.info.email ).first

      # Create the user if its a new registeration
      if user.nil?
        user = User.new email: auth.info.email, password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

        #Disable confirmation so we don't need to send confirmation email
        # user.skip_confirmation!

        user.save!
      end
    end

    # Associate the identity with the user if needed
    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end

    # Get the basic information and create Profile, Address model
    unless user.profile.present?
      first_name = auth.info.first_name.present? ? auth.info.first_name : auth.info.name.split(' ')[0]
      last_name = auth.info.last_name.present? ? auth.info.last_name : auth.info.name.split(' ')[1]
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: user.id,
                            first_name: first_name,
                            last_name: last_name,
                            gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender)
      profile.save(validate: false)
      address = Address.new(addressable_id: profile.id, addressable_type: 'Profile')
      address.save(validate: false)
    end
    user.reload
  end
```

The exception raises on `user.save!` Is it possible to redirect the user to some other page, or just to show a flash message? I know that the business logic, such as redirect and other stuff, has to be executed in the controller. So, maybe, there is a way to move the method I've written above to the controller? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Why would you want to move it to the controller, It seems like it should be in the model like you did, You could check if it is valid or not before saving it or catch the exception in the controller and doing redirection/rendering, So redirecting with a flash message seems to be nice, If you made some validations in the front-end form too It would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`rescue_from`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) class method in your controller.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

    rescue_from ::ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :validation_failed

    ...

    def validation_failed(exception)
       flash[:error] = exception.message
       redirect_to request.referer || root_path
    end

end
```